# What I need to upgrade in this case the in laravel 5.1 Cannot use String as class name as it is reserved?

Tags: php, laravel

I use laravel 5.1, apache 2.4 + nginx1.9 and php 7.0.0. How to decide my problem with "Cannot use 'String' as class name as it is reserved"?

What should I update?

Comment: It says, you cannot use `String` as a class name since it's already reserved in php. Try using some other name for your class.

Comment: If you didn't create a class named String, run `composer update` to update your packages. There's at least 2 packages out there that I see that use a String class.

Comment: Could you provide the *exact error message you receive*. There maybe details there which you've overlooked and will give someone the right clue to help you.

Comment: Composer didn't update  http://postimg.org/image/q1pw2osmv/

Answer (score 0):

In PHP 5.6 `String` class is OK and everything runs just fine, so you should either downgrade or rename your class.

Here's a [GitHub discussion](https://github.com/Respect/Validation/issues/362) on the topic.

In your particular case, `String` class comes from packages. So the easiest way to fix this would be to downgrade to PHP 5.6.

Comment: I have tried create a new controller,
That's what happened http://s019.radikal.ru/i641/1602/38/134c85b89248.png

Comment: @HeartOfprogrammer Updated the answer

Comment: Я использую уже 5,6 PHP http://s020.radikal.ru/i706/1602/37/32d65dc750b0.png But the problem stays

Comment: @HeartOfprogrammer You're using it from CLI, so check it running `php -v`

Comment: @HeartOfprogrammer I'm also Russian, so it's not a problem for me, but I think you'd better use English here :)  `Я использую уже 5,6`

Comment: Я что-то вас не до конца понял, где мне использовать английский?) Вы имеете ввиду типо мне больше сидеть на этом сайте? И писать на английском?

Comment: @HeartOfprogrammer сайт на английском, комьюнити со всего мира, так что писать стоит на английском.

Answer (score 0):

It says, you cannot use `String` as a class name since it's already reserved in `php 7`. Try using some other name for your class.

Try upgrading your php parser. It's using `String_` instead of `String`. 
: https://github.com/nikic/PHP-Parser/blob/master/lib/PhpParser/Node/Scalar/String_.php#L8

Comment: Where is a php parser have? How I will find php parser?